# How to give fading effect to slide

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to give some fading effect to my slide view using JavaScript in asp.net

I am able to give slide views but not able to give fading effect for slide changing

Each slide has a link to redirect to other page

My code follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var image1 = new Image()
    image1.src="images/SAM_0043.JPG"
    var image2 = new Image()
    image2.src = "images/SAM_0047.JPG"
    var image3 = new Image()
    image3.src="images/SAM_0044.JPG"
</script>

<body>
    <a href="javascript:slidelink()">
        <img src="images/SAM_0043.JPG" name="slide" border="0" style="width: 603px; height: 373px; z-index: 1; border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;left: 295px; top: 224px; position: absolute" />
    </a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var step = 1
    var whichimage = 1
     function slideit() {
         if (!document.images)
             return
          document.images.slide.src = eval("image" + step + ".src")
          whichimage = step
         if (step < 3)
             step++
          else
             step = 1
         setTimeout("slideit()", 1800)
      }
      slideit()
      function slidelink() {
            if (whichimage == 1)
             window.location = "link1.htm"
         else if (whichimage == 2)
             window.location = "link2.htm"
          else if (whichimage == 3)
              window.location = "link3.htm"
      }
    //-->
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't see that you have put any effort in solving this by yourself. Not even the slightest indication in your code. That is against the rules. However, [here is a little tip](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/), since you tagged jQuery. Although I also don't see that you're even using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use jQuery `.slideToggle()` it does a slide fading effect.